# How to pass data from interceptor response or interceptor error to other components in React

Tags: reactjs, interceptor, react-typescript

I need to pass data from interceptor response/error to other components

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    if (response.headers.TestFlag === 'True') {
//Pass data to other component
    }
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    if(error.response.data!=null && error.response.data.title==='Generic error'){
//Pass error details to component
    }
    return Promise.reject(console.error);

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of component communication method .e.g. Redux, MobX. After the error was thrown, you can catch it pass to appropriate reducer and use it in your component.

Comment: could you share some example as i am new to React

Comment: Firstly, you have to integrate Redux into your project, details could be found at https://redux.js.org and https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react. Then once you have the `store` object, each time error appear you inform all component about the error .e.g. `store.dispatch({ type: 'ERROR', error })`